# jQuery target div with style

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a background for a div using jQuery:

```
$(".cover").css("background", "yellow");
```

However I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of null

Also tried with adding an id instead of a class:

```
$("cover").css("background", "yellow");
```

but then it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'css'

Source code: http://pastebin.com/FEVwL8iq

Comment: do you do that after the document is loaded?

Comment: A JSfiddle would be nice. Or just some HTML to go with this JS.

Comment: In your second example, to select an ID you must use a hash tag, e.g. `$("#cover")`

Comment: Source code: http://pastebin.com/FEVwL8iq

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$`? It might be that some other script has overwritten jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I can see you're using Mootools on the page as well.

Mootools has probably assigned it self to $. Try changing the expression to this:

`jQuery(".cover").css("background", "yellow");`

Comment: usually wnen jQuery isn't include it says `$ is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

if you've a div

```
<div class="cover">...</div>
```

try using.

```
$('.cover').addClass('yellow-class');
```

and for remove class

```
$('.cover').removeClass('yellow-class');


<style>
    .yellow-class {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>
```